# Terminology in graph theory

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology

Let $G$ be a finite graph with the following property:

> For any vertex $a$ and edge $\{b, c\}$ of $G$, there is an edge connecting them: there is one of $\{a,b\}$ or $\{a, c\}$ in $G$.

Is there a common terminology in graph theory?

Comment: Isn't that just a complete graph?

Comment: @RaceBannon consider the 3-path.

Comment: I don't know the terminology; just to clarify: Are $b$ and $c$ assumed to be different from $a$?

Comment: @joriki: Yes, suppose that $a$ is different from both $b$ and $c$.

Comment: @Race Bannon: complete graphs, star graphs, and any complete multipartite graphs have the property.

Comment: I think you can say the graph has diameter $2$ (longest distance between any two nodes). Or $1$ if it happens to be a complete graph.

Comment: @MickA: There is a graph having diameter 2 but not having above property: Consider a triangle with a tail ($K_3 = \{a, b, c\} \cup \{d\}$ where $d$ is connected with $a$.) Then it has diameter 2, but for $d$ and $ \{b, c\}$, there is no connecting edge.

Comment: Is there at **least** one edge or **exactly** one edge connecting them?

Comment: @Marconius: At least one.

Answer (score 1):

The condition says that a subgraph induced by 3 vertices cannot have exactly one edge.  The graph with three vertices and exactly one edge is $\overline{P_3}$, where $P_3$ denotes the path on three vertices.  Graphs that do not have a particular graph $H$ as an induced subgraph are often called *$H$-free* graphs.  So, these graphs are *$\overline{P_3}$-free* graphs.

As observed in the comments, complete multipartite graphs are $\overline{P_3}$-free.  In fact, it is not hard to show that a graph is $\overline{P_3}$-free if and only if it is complete multipartite or an empty graph.